# Como fazer um select no banco para não trazer valores repetidos?

Tags: mysql, sql, query

Por exemplo tem na tabela o valores: verde, vermelho, azul, azul, rosa, rosa, rosa, amarelo. Eu precisaria retornar da tabela cores apenas uma vez o azul e o rosa. Tem alguma forma de fazer isso?

Comment: Acessada 26 mil vezes e com três upvotes apenas.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use `DISTINCT` irá retornar sem repetir:

```
SELECT DISTINCT cor FROM Cores;
```

uma outra solução pouco ortodoxa seria usar GROUP BY:

```
SELECT cor FROM Cores GROUP BY cor;
```

Comment: isso mesmo, eu tinha esquecido.

Comment: Acredito que o `GROUP BY` seja melhor, já tive melhorias absurdas de performance ao trocar o `DISTINCT` por um `GROUP BY` nas mesmas `queries`.

Inclusive tinha uma `query` que levava aproximadamente 30 segundos para rodar, e o processo dela na lista de processos ficava pelo menos 28 segundos como "Removendo duplicidade" basicamente, então tirei o `DISTINCT` e coloquei um `GROUP BY` no final, e de 30 segundos caiu para 0,8 segundos.

Comment: @BrunoHenrique a pergunta agora seria por que o `GROUP BY` é mais rápido que o `DISTINCT`

Answer (score 8):

```
SELECT DISTINCT cor, outra_coluna_se_quiser FROM cores;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Select/Distinct.sql).

O segredo aí é o [`DISTINCT`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-distinct-keyword.htm). Ele seleciona só as linhas de forma única, sem repetir o valor da coluna.

[Documentação](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html). [Otimização](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/distinct-optimization.html).

Comment: obrigado tinha esquecido disto!

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM cores
```

Você também pode usar um GROUP BY para agrupar as cores:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM cores GROUP BY cor
```

Comment: Desculpe, mas não é exatamente o que foi respondido pelo [Ricardo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/74677/5878)?

Comment: Verdade, sou novo aqui ainda tô aprendendo a usar...

Comment: Comece fazendo o [tour] então, lá dá um panorama geral de como funciona o site.

Comment: Valeu! Vou fazer sim :]

Answer (score 0):

E neste caso,

onde tenho uma seleção de várias colunas e tenho mais de um registro codigobarras para um id.produto. Mas a quantidade se refere a um mesmo objeto, não podendo fazer o GROUP BY com SUM.

SELECT logtroca.id_loja,produtoautomacao.codigobarras,logtroca.id_produto, produto.descricaocompleta, logtroca.quantidade, fornecedor.razaosocial,usuario.nome,tipomotivotroca.descricao, logtroca.observacaotroca
from logtroca
inner join produto
on produto.id=logtroca.id_produto
inner join fornecedor
on produto.id_fornecedorfabricante=fornecedor.id
inner join tipomotivotroca
on tipomotivotroca.id=logtroca.id_motivotroca
inner join usuario
on usuario.id=logtroca.id_usuario
inner join produtoautomacao
on produtoautomacao.id_produto=logtroca.id_produto
where datamovimento ='#Periodo:7::::0:#' and logtroca.id_tipoentradasaida=0
AND LOGTROCA.id_loja = #Loja:3:Loja:::0:true:# and USUARIO.id_loja = #Loja:3:Loja:::0:true:#

este ´pe o retorno

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Se tiver uma nova pergunta, faça-a clicando no botão [Fazer pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Inclua um link para esta pergunta se ajudar a fornecer contexto. - [Da Revisão](/review/late-answers/373834)

Answer (score 0):

se o problema for trazer apenas uma coluna diferente o distinct deve bastar

```
SELECT DISTINCT COR FROM TABELA_CORES
```

caso tenha que trazer outra coluna junto como por exemplo o id dessa cor, o "GROUP BY" se torna uma boa opção sendo necessário dizer se quer o ultimo ou o primeiro valor da coluna

```
SELECT MAX(ID), COR FROM TABELA_CORES GROUP BY COR
```

Comment: Não necessariamente você vai querer trazer o id junto

Comment: Não foi exatamente isso que foi respondido em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/74677/5878?